# run a service indefinitely

Tags: android, service, android-asynctask, background

I am creating an application that sends and receives data from the server all the time. I need it to update the data as soon as possible, because every second is changing online data. I created this class, but it does not work, hangs at one time. Wonder if this "while (true)" is the correct way to do the functions run indefinitely because it does not find anything more like

```
    package nilson.online; /**
* Created by nilso_000 on 23/07/2015.
*/
import android.app.Service;
    import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import nilson.BancoDados;
//this class contains a basic instructions to open a web page and send a POST form
import static nilson.online.ServiceOnline.executaHttpPost;

public class ServiceFilaOnlineB extends Service {

String metodo="";
String url="";
ArrayList<NameValuePair> parametrosPost;

public SQLiteDatabase banco = null;
private BancoDados gerenciaBanco;

public ServiceFilaOnlineB(){}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service was Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    try {
        banco = openOrCreateDatabase("LNM", MODE_MULTI_PROCESS, null);
        gerenciaBanco = new BancoDados();
        gerenciaBanco.abrirBD(banco);
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("LNM erro servico1", "error to init the service " + e);
        onDestroy();
    }try {
        //Here I create the loop that will run indefinitely in android
        //even to restart the system. It has two functions:
        //1-check for updates offline and send then to the server online
        //2-chec for updates online and copy then to the SQLite offline
        while(true) {
            //This is the records of updates offline
            Cursor c = gerenciaBanco.getFilaOnline();
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                url = "http://192.168.10.100/lnm/add.php";
                metodo = "POST";
                Log.e("LNM Fila", "Size of fila: " + c.getCount());
                do {
                    parametrosPost = new ArrayList<>();
                    parametrosPost.add(new BasicNameValuePair("SQL", c.getString(0)));

                    new InsertDataTask().execute(parametrosPost);
                    new GetDataTask().execute(parametrosPost);
                } while (c.moveToNext());
            }
            Thread.sleep(5 * 1000);
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("LNM erro servico2", "error to init the service " + e);
        onDestroy();
    }
}
private class InsertDataTask extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<NameValuePair>, String, String> {

    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        Log.e("LNM Resultado", "Command executed "+result);
        result = result.replaceAll("\\s+"," ").trim();
        Log.e("LNM", "" + result.substring(0,6));

        if("INSERT".equals(result.substring(0,6))) {
            String res[]=result.split("\\|");
            Log.e("LNM Comando Online", "The record was inserted int the db ONLINE and returned the ID " + res[1]);
        }else
            Log.e("LNM Conexao realizada", "Error " + result);
    }

    private String executa(ArrayList<NameValuePair>... params){
        String result;
        try {
            result = executaHttpPost(url, params[0]);
            Log.d("LNM Conectado"," Command executed "+result);
            return result;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("LNM Error on POST",""+e);
            return  executa(params);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(ArrayList<NameValuePair>... params) {
        return executa(params);
    }
}
private class GetDataTask extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<NameValuePair>, String, String> {

    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        Log.e("LNM Resultado", "Command executed "+result);
        result = result.replaceAll("\\s+"," ").trim();
        Log.e("LNM", "" + result.substring(0,6));
        //Separate results by | and insert in db
        if("SUCESS".equals(result.substring(0,6))) {
            String res[]=result.split("\\|");
            Log.e("LNM Comando Online", "Data updated " + res[1]);
            //Updating the record OFFLINE with the ID ONLINE
            gerenciaBanco.updateMatch("online", res);
        }else
            Log.e("LNM Conexao realizada", "Error " + result);
    }

    private String executa(ArrayList<NameValuePair>... params){
        String result;
        try {
            result = executaHttpPost(url, params[0]);
            Log.d("LNM Conectado"," Command executed "+result);
            return result;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("LNM Error on POST",""+e);
            return  executa(params);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(ArrayList<NameValuePair>... params) {
        return executa(params);
    }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}
```

}

Comment: Could you elaborate on exactly what's going wrong?

Comment: We will need more information about what your expected behavior is and how your current code is not meeting those expectations in order to help. Also to have a `while(true)` loop in your `Service` class does not sound like a good idea at all. This will continue to keep the devices data connection open at all times and will drain the battery quickly.

Comment: I want to make a similar function as the Whatsapp function that check for new messages all the time. My code runs function doInBackground few times and stops. And the function OnPostExecute not run